# How to list all final level of subfolders in a directory in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a directory that contains more than 5000 subfolders. I need to get the name of the folders in the final level i.e. the sub-sub-sub...folders that have no subfolders and list them in a listbox.

But the 1st level subfolders and the 2nd...3rd.. that still contain subfolders are not needed to be listed, but only the last-level subfolders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub GetChildFolders(sFolderPath As String)
    For Each dir As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sFolderPath)
        If IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length > 0 Then
            Call GetChildFolders(dir)
        Else
            ' Add "dir" to the ListBox
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And then call it with the father directory where all starts:

```
Call GetChildFolders(startFolder)
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe you could do something like this to get rid of the amount of folders:

```
Dim allDirs() As String = IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each dir As String In AllDirs
    If IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length = 0 Then
        ' Add "dir" to the ListBox
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What you have posted is clearly fine where small number of sub-folders are there, but in my case I have more than 5 thousands sub-folders and when I tried your code I got an error message: "The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xca9890 to COM context 0xca9ae0 for 60 seconds..."

How do I get rid from this messsage? it seems something related to running time and memory...

Comment: Yes, it is a limit of 60 seconds for the time of a recursive function to finalize. I edited my answer. Hope it helps